# WinInet not working in Windows 7 - Dev-C++

Tags: file, makefile, ftp, wininet

I'm new to C++ (not to programming) and I was looking for a simple way to upload and download files from my ftp server. I have been looking around the Internet for 3 hours at least and I couldn't find anything. I have tried to use libcurl but It's to confusing for me. Then, I have found something about some libraries with the header <afxinet.h> that may work, but it's not included in Dev-C++ and I didn't know where to download it. Finally I found the library wininet but if I try to include it on my project I get this error:

[image: Click to see Image]

And here is where the problem is supposed to be:
[image: Click to see Image]

So, if anyone knows how to solve this problem, or know another easy way to upload files to FTP with C++, I'll be very grateful.

Some Info:
OS: Windows 7 sp 3
Environment: Dev-C++ 5.11

Comment: Please don't post links to other sites, and don't post images.  Doing so makes it hard for others to learn from your question in the future and means we can't cut and paste things for answers.  Instead of images, cut and paste the error messages and code into your question, and format them properly for SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have found the solution: the problem was that the version of the Dev-C++ compiler was outdated, so I downloaded and installed CodeBlocks. When I ran the code again, I get the error Undefined reference to '__imp__InternetOpenA and I found the solution here: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/windows/59273/
Flareonz44